# Restore Ubuntu After deleting Partition table

Tags: partitioning, 18.04

I was using Ubuntu and I accidentally removed the partition table using program 'disks'.

Is there any way I can restore Ubuntu or even the files that were on the Ubuntu partition?
It's unallocated space now!

Comment: Only with data recovery software.

Comment: Yes I used TestDisk and it worked